# SparseLU and SparseQR get differen result in complex matrix

Tags: eigen

I've tried to use sparse QR and LU to solve complex cases in my FEA program and it seems that QR and BiCGSTAB method cannot get correct result.
Meanwhile BiCGSTAB with IncompleteLUT is okay.
Eigen version 3.3.1 with mingw-x86_64 gcc 6.2

smallest code

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

using namespace std::complex_literals;

struct mat_cell
{
    int row;
    int col;
    double value;
};
// matrix data.
mat_cell mat01[]={
    { 0,  0,  40432.2974517006}, { 0,  6, -20216.1487258503}, { 0, 12, -20216.1487258503},
    { 1,  1,  180.518062136147}, { 1,  7, -90.2590310680736}, { 1, 11, -9025.90310680736},
    { 1, 13, -90.2590310680736}, { 1, 17,  9025.90310680736}, 
    { 2,  2,  180.518062136147}, { 2,  8, -90.2590310680736}, { 2, 10,  9025.90310680736},
    { 2, 14, -90.2590310680736}, { 2, 16, -9025.90310680736},
    { 3,  3,  456735.213970955}, { 3,  9, -228367.606985477}, { 3, 15, -228367.606985477},
    { 4,  4,  2421773.15749991}, { 4,  8, -9025.90310680736}, { 4, 10,  594294.042611519},
    { 4, 14,  9025.90310680736}, { 4, 16,  594294.042611519},
    { 5,  5,  2421773.15749991}, { 5,  7,  9025.90310680736}, { 5, 11,  594294.042611519},
    { 5, 13, -9025.90310680736}, { 5, 17,  594294.042611519},
    { 6,  0, -20216.1487258503}, { 6,  6,  40432.2974517006}, { 6, 24, -20216.1487258503},
    { 7,  1, -90.2590310680736}, { 7,  5,  9025.90310680736}, { 7,  7,  180.518062136147},
    { 7, 25, -90.2590310680736}, { 7, 29, -9025.90310680736},
    { 8,  2, -90.2590310680736}, { 8,  4, -9025.90310680736}, { 8,  8,  180.518062136147},
    { 8, 26, -90.2590310680736}, { 8, 28,  9025.90310680736},
    { 9,  3, -228367.606985477}, { 9,  9,  456735.213970955}, { 9, 27, -228367.606985477},
    {10,  2,  9025.90310680736}, {10,  4,  594294.042611519}, {10, 10,  2421773.15749991},
    {10, 26, -9025.90310680736}, {10, 28,  594294.042611519},
    {11,  1, -9025.90310680736}, {11,  5,  594294.042611519}, {11, 11,  2421773.15749991},
    {11, 25,  9025.90310680736}, {11, 29,  594294.042611519},
    {12,  0, -20216.1487258503}, {12, 12,  20216.1487258503},
    {13,  1, -90.2590310680736}, {13,  5, -9025.90310680736}, {13, 13,  90.2590310680736},
    {13, 17, -9025.90310680736},
    {14,  2, -90.2590310680736}, {14,  4,  9025.90310680736}, {14, 14,  90.2590310680736},
    {14, 16,  9025.90310680736},
    {15,  3, -228367.606985477}, {15, 15,  228367.606985477},
    {16,  2, -9025.90310680736}, {16,  4,  594294.042611519}, {16, 14,  9025.90310680736},
    {16, 16,  1210886.57874995},
    {17,  1,  9025.90310680736}, {17,  5,  594294.042611519}, {17, 13, -9025.90310680736},
    {17, 17,  1210886.57874995},
    {18, 18,  40432.2974517006}, {18, 24, -20216.1487258503},
    {19, 19,  180.518062136147}, {19, 25, -90.2590310680736}, {19, 29,  9025.90310680736},
    {20, 20,  180.518062136147}, {20, 26, -90.2590310680736}, {20, 28, -9025.90310680736},
    {21, 21,  456735.213970955}, {21, 27, -228367.606985477},
    {22, 22,  2421773.15749991}, {22, 26,  9025.90310680736}, {22, 28,  594294.042611519},
    {23, 23,  2421773.15749991}, {23, 25, -9025.90310680736}, {23, 29,  594294.042611519},
    {24,  6, -20216.1487258503}, {24, 18, -20216.1487258503}, {24, 24,  40432.2974517006},
    {25,  7, -90.2590310680736}, {25, 11,  9025.90310680736}, {25, 19, -90.2590310680736},
    {25, 23, -9025.90310680736}, {25, 25,  180.518062136147},
    {26,  8, -90.2590310680736}, {26, 10, -9025.90310680736}, {26, 20, -90.2590310680736},
    {26, 22,  9025.90310680736}, {26, 26,  180.518062136147},
    {27,  9, -228367.606985477}, {27, 21, -228367.606985477}, {27, 27,  456735.213970955},
    {28,  8,  9025.90310680736}, {28, 10,  594294.042611519}, {28, 20, -9025.90310680736},
    {28, 22,  594294.042611519}, {28, 28,  2421773.15749991},
    {29,  7, -9025.90310680736}, {29, 11,  594294.042611519}, {29, 19,  9025.90310680736},
    {29, 23,  594294.042611519}, {29, 29,  2421773.15749991}};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nn{30};

    Eigen::MatrixXcd A_dens = Eigen::MatrixXcd::Zero(nn, nn);
    Eigen::VectorXcd rhs    = Eigen::VectorXcd::Zero(nn);

    Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>> A_sp(nn, nn);
    std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<std::complex<double>>> triList;

    double yita{0.02};// small imag.
    for(auto const cell: mat01){
        A_dens(cell.row, cell.col) = cell.value*(1.+yita*1.0i);
        triList.push_back({cell.row, cell.col, cell.value*(1.+yita*1.0i)});
    }
    A_sp.setFromTriplets(triList.begin(), triList.end());
    triList.clear();
    A_sp.makeCompressed();

    int ix[]={12, 13, 14};
    double scale{1.e60};// Large than 1e38.

    for(auto const j: ix){
        A_dens(j, j) *= scale;
        A_sp.coeffRef(j, j) *= scale;
    }

    rhs(ix[1]) = 0.618*A_sp.coeff(ix[1], ix[1]);

    // solve by dense LU method. 
    Eigen::VectorXcd x_lu = A_dens.lu().solve(rhs);

    // define sparse solver.
    Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int>> solver_lu;
    Eigen::SparseQR<Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int>> solver_qr;
    Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>>> solver_bi;
    Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::complex<double>>, Eigen::IncompleteLUT<std::complex<double>, int>> solver_bi_2;

    solver_lu.compute(A_sp);
    if(solver_lu.info()!=Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)std::cout << "SparseLU decomposition failed!\n";
    Eigen::VectorXcd x_sp_lu   = solver_lu.solve(rhs);
    if(solver_lu.info()!=Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)std::cout << "SparseLU solve failed!\n";

    solver_qr.compute(A_sp);
    if(solver_qr.info()!=Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)std::cout << "SparseQR decomposition failed!\n";
    Eigen::VectorXcd x_sp_qr   = solver_qr.solve(rhs);
    if(solver_qr.info()!=Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)std::cout << "SparseQR solve failed!\n";

    solver_bi.compute(A_sp);
    if(solver_bi.info()!=Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)std::cout << "SparseBi decomposition failed!\n";
    Eigen::VectorXcd x_sp_bi   = solver_bi.solve(rhs);
    if(solver_bi.info()!=Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)std::cout << "SparseBi solve failed!\n";

    solver_bi_2.compute(A_sp);
    if(solver_bi_2.info()!=Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)std::cout << "SparseBi2 decomposition failed!\n";
    Eigen::VectorXcd x_sp_bi_2 = solver_bi_2.solve(rhs);
    if(solver_bi_2.info()!=Eigen::ComputationInfo::Success)std::cout << "SparseBi2 solve failed!\n";

    std::cout << "No | Dense LU | SparseLU | SparseQR | BiCGSTAB |BiCGSTAB+ILUT|\n";
    std::cout << "---|---|---|---|---|---|\n";
    for(int i=0; i<nn; i++){
        std::cout << i << "|";
        std::cout << x_lu(i) << "|";
        std::cout << x_sp_lu(i) << "|";
        std::cout << x_sp_qr(i) << "|";
        std::cout << x_sp_bi(i) << "|";
        std::cout << x_sp_bi_2(i) << "|\n";
    }
}
```

**Method**                  X(1) X(5)

**DenseLU**       (0.435087,-1.73121e-017)   (0.0008897,7.91857e-020)

**SparseLU** (0.435087,3.61979e-017)    (0.0008897,-1.2936e-019)

**SparseQR**        (0,0)                       (0,0)

**BiCGSTAB** (0.187474,-8.66607e-019)  (0.00139743,-2.34841e-021)

**BiCGSTAB+ILUT** (0.435068,1.58791e-017)  (0.000889823,-1.00545e-019)

[*More detailed result compare picture*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc0UO.png)

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a smaller matrix? What is the condition number of the matrix you are using? Is the matrix invertible (if not you'll not get a unique solution).

Comment: How different are the results you are seeing - and how close can you realistically expect them to be?

Comment: Hi @MichaelAnderson, you can see in result vector x(1) and x(5) both LU  and BiCGSTAB+ILUT methods is okay but QR and BiCGSTAB seems not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is highly singular. For double precision numbers, the rank of your matrix is 3 only, because of your weird scaling of 3 columns. There is thus an infinite space of solution to your problem. If you look at the relative error: `(A*x-b).norm()/b.norm()`, you get:

```
No  | Dense LU   | SparseLU   | SparseQR   | BiCGSTAB   |BiCGSTAB+ILUT
--- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |-------------
res | 3.6633e-74 | 1.4915e-74 | 3.1977e-18 | 1.9095e-59 | 2.67692e-63
```

meaning that all results are "correct" with respect to the precision of double precision floating point numbers.